# Log4j2 RollingFile Not Working

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I started using Log4j2 on the system i am currently developing.
And I encountered some problems.

here is my **log4j2.properties** file.

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console, rolling, list

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:catalina.home}/logs/beo.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:catalina.home}/logs/beo-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

appender.list.type = List
appender.list.name = List
appender.list.filters = threshold
appender.list.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.list.filter.threshold.level = error

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Here is the **login method** where i tried to test logging.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager
            .getLogger(NavigationController.class.getName());

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" })
    public ModelAndView loginPage(
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();

        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            mv.setViewName("redirect:/auth/panel");

        } else {
            if (error != null) {
                mv.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
                LOGGER.debug("debug");
                LOGGER.info("info");
                LOGGER.error("error");
                LOGGER.warn("warning");
                LOGGER.fatal("fatal");
            }
            mv.setViewName("login");
        }

        return mv;
    }
```

[image]

The RollingFile doesn't seem to work. It creates a log file named beo.logs but it's also empty. Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Logger name is shown as being somepackage.NavigationController. Surely the package it is in is not org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling, which is the only Logger you have configured to go to the RollingFileAppender. I suspect you really want to use the package name of NavigationController.